# FireFox doesn't show my XML properly

Tags: xml, firefox

I'm playing with some `XML` processing methods and I'v had a wierd problem which is that I see two different views of my `XML` file when I see my `XML` file using the `IE` browser and when I see it using the `FireFox`. When I open the file in the `IE`, I see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="property" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="property">
        <xsl:number />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, in the `FireFox`, I see the below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="property" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="property">
        <xsl:number />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, I know the problem is the `FireFox` isn't showing the `xmlns` attribute. I tried to find a way to resolve it; but had no luck. Anyone has encountered this problem before and know how to solve it? Thanks.

PS: I am using IE 9.0.8112.16421 and Firefox 15.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=175946

Basically, Firefox actually uses XSLT to implement the XML prettyprinter and XSLT can't work with xmlns attributes...

Comment: What then would be the solution? there must be a way!

Comment: Well, short of rewriting the XML prettyprinter in Firefox?  ;)  There must be a way, but it must not be easy....